# Was sind gute Zungenbrecher im Deutschen? / What are good German tongue-twisters?

Tags: big-list

Welche Zungenbrecher im Deutschen sind besonders interessant oder eine gute Übung?

Comment: Should this be community wiki?

Comment: Siehe auch: [Zungenbrecher](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zungenbrecher) auf Wikipedia.

Comment: @Tim Probably. But I am not sure that anyone can convert it now.

Comment: @thei: Ah, sorry. I'll go vote some of your questions up. ;)

Comment: Note that I opened a meta thread on this: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/20/are-the-following-two-big-list-questions-posted-by-me-welcome-here

Comment: Aber Obacht bei der WP-Seite (okay, sollte man bei WP nicht extra erwähnen müssen): da sind einige "Zungenbrecher" dabei die keine sind.  (Editieren?  WP?  Nee, tu ich mir nicht mehr an)

Comment: @Shog9 Wouldn't it have been better to let people discuss on meta and then vote for closing?

Comment: @thei: that's still ongoing, but I'm not really seeing any support...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die bekanntesten, die mir einfallen:

- Fischers Fritz fischt frische Fische; frische Fische fischt Fischers Fritz.
- Blaukraut bleibt Blaukraut und Brautkleid bleibt Brautkleid. Brautkleid bleibt Brautkleid und Blaukraut bleibt Blaukraut.
- Der Whiskeymixer mixt den Whiskey für den Whiskeymixer. Für den Whiskeymixer mixt der Whiskeymixer den Whiskey.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very demanding one in Bernese:

> Uf der Rapperswilerbrügg stö drü
>   düüri, lääri Röhrli. Dür die drü
>   düüre, lääre Röhrli leere d'Lüt rächt
>   rede.

Translation: Three lean and empty straws stand on the bridge of Rapperswil, through those three lean and empty straws the people learn to speak correctly.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> Der Potsdamer Postkutscher putzt den Potsdamer Postkutschkasten.

If you can say that 10 times in a row, you shouldn't have difficulties with "s" and "sch" anymore.

Comment: Ich kenn das mit dem "Cottbuser Postkutscher", was noch einen schönen Konsonantentausch hineinbringt...

Answer (score 3):

Susi stolpert über einen spitzen Stein.

to practice "s"/"sch"-sounds.

Answer (score 2):

A tongue twister in Austrian dialect where some vowels are contracted:

Zwanz'g z'quetschte Zwetschken und zwanz'g z'quetschte Zwetschken san vierz'g z'quetschte Zwetschken.

(Twenty squashed plums and twenty squashed plums are forty squashed plums.)

Answer (score 2):

Streichholzschächtelchen - Matchbox

Comment: I thought this was only used to depress French people :)

Comment: This is more of a [shibboleth](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/167/66) than a tongue twister, because most native speakers have no problems pronouncing the word...