# Schibboleths für verschiedene norddeutsche Regionen?

Tags: single-word-request, pronunciation, dialect, regional, northern-german

[Schibboleths](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schibboleth) sind Wörter, anhand deren Aussprache man die Herkunft des Sprechers zuordnen kann. Ganz allgemeines Beispiel für Muttersprachler vs. Ausländer: *"Streichholzschächtelchen"*.

Für den süddeutschen Raum gibt es [jede Menge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schibboleth#Schibboleths_im_deutschsprachigen_Raum) davon auf Wikipedia, aber für die Norddeutschen wird es schwierig.

Welches Schibboleth wäre beispielsweise geeignet, um einen Holsteiner von einem Mecklenburger zu unterscheiden?

Comment: In Österreich sagt man "Streichholzschachtel" (und ja, man kann das obige trotzdem aussprechen).

Comment: This is a *very* open ended question. I suggest you restrict its scope more tightly such that there's one correct answer.

Comment: Kann sein, dass sie in Vergessenheit geraten sind, weil die ursprünglichen norddeutschen Dialekte (Plattdeutsch) immer mehr aussterben.

Comment: @stefano I have already narrowed it down from general shibboleths to just those for northern Germany. Since there even don't seem to be that many distinct dialects left today (see ladybug's comment), my fear is that narrowing that question down further would kill it off. Maybe nobody knows a shibboleth to distinguish someone from Holstein from a Mecklenburger, but I'd be equally happy to learn about one for Niedersachsen or Hamburg.

Comment: @thei danke und 'tschuldige :-) Hab's von spezifisch deutschen Muttersprachlern zu allgemeinen Muttersprachlern abgeändert.

Comment: @Jan that sounds very sensible. I was just reminded of some very bad "list examples of x" type of questions.

Comment: @stefano yes, I know these. In fact, I sometimes tend to fall into the same trap, so thanks for making me think about it once more :-)

Comment: @Phira:  Nur wenige Österreicher sagen »Streichholzschachtel«. »Zündholzschachtel« ist wesentlich verbreiteter. - Ist aber ohnehin off topic.

Answer (score 8):

Wären Worte, die mit "st" beginnen, ein Beispiel, anhand dessen man (manche) Hamburger erkennen kann?

Berliner/Brandenburger erkennt man beispielsweise daran, dass sie häufig "Kirche" aussprechen wie "Kirsche", also: "Kürsche". In Westdeutschland hingegen sagt man oft "Kierche" mit langem ih.

Comment: das stimmt, viele Norddeutsche nutzen "st" wie im Englischen...

Answer (score 8):

In the region of Hannover, the s in sp/st combinations is pronounces as an actual s, whereas elsewhere it often is a sch to a varying degree ("Er stolperte über einen spitzen Stein" vs. "Er schtolperte über einen schpitzen Schtein").

Somebody from Kiel or other parts of northern Schleswig-Holstein will often turn -er word endings into ä (a-umlaut) - "Er ist ein Kielä und trinkt Biä". In extreme cases they will also drop the t from -st word endings, "Wurst" wird "Wurs". Speaking that way is considered a bit redneckish, though.

Comment: I always thought that "stolpern übern spitzen Stein" would be a Hamburg phenomenon only - thanks for that :-) The "ä" thing is also very common in Mecklenburg (Bäckä, Fleischä), although not the t-dropping, so this might be something specific to northern Schleswig-Holstein.

Comment: Don't they even say *Wuäs* for "Wurst"? As a berliner, I would probably say *Wohst*.

Comment: I find the dropping of hard consonant endings quite common and neither extreme nor "redneckish" at all! (I'm from the Oldenburg/Bremen region). Actually I would even go so far as to consider it overly formal to pronounce these endings (unless combined with a different dialect).

Answer (score 3):

Berliner sprechen das 'i' gerne wie 'ü' (siehe fzwos Antwort), das 'ä' wie 'e(h)' und 'qu' wie 'kw'. Also:

Kürche statt Kirche,
Bestehtigung statt Bestätigung und
bekwem statt bequem.

Im schnellen Redefluss ist das praktisch (praktüsch) nicht zu verhindern.

Comment: Dass *qu* wie *kw* ausgesprochen wird, ist standard für die deutsche Sprache. Es war sehr viel lustiger für meine Komillitonen (und mich) als ein Professor öfters *Kuäcksilber* erwähnt hat.

Comment: ferner wird die Endung "er" üblicherweise "a" ausgesprochen: "Ick bin Balina und keen Baua."

Answer (score 3):

Ich hatte eine Kollegin aus Pommern (nicht Mecklenburg, das war ihr ganz wichtig!). Grundsätzlich hätte ich ihren Dialekt als Mischung aus berlinerisch und dem typischen Norddeutsch beschrieben. Ich bin dann ihre Kernsätze nach Schibboleths durchgegangen. Eingefallen ist mir:

- Sie hat *er* sehr stark als *ä* ausgesprochen, soweit, dass sie auf dem Doktorhut eine *Aktion Sommäfiguä* (sic!) aufgeklebt bekommen hat; und
- Sie hat aktiv das Wort *lütt* verwendet. Als Außenseiter weiß ich nicht, wie stark es im hohen Norden verbreitet ist, aber eine andere Kollegin aus der Gegend um Nienburg hat gemeint, dass es bei ihr nicht verbreitet sei.
- Sie hat an viele Stellen ostdeutsche Ausdrücke bevorzugt benutzt (Plaste und Elaste, Eierkuchen statt Pfannkuchen, Kosmonaut, Pfannkuchen statt Krapfen, und andere, die mir gerade nicht einfallen)

Im [**Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache**](http://atlas-alltagssprache.de) habe ich auch folgende potenziellen Unterscheidungsmerkmale gefunden:

- Aussprache von *sp-* und *st-*: [image: Spitzer-Stein-Karte]
- *Wurzel* statt *Mohrrübe*: [image: Rübenkarte]
- Uhrzeiten als *Viertel neun* oder *zehn vor halb* [image: Uhrzeitkarte]

Dann habe ich aufgehört zu suchen.

Comment: Sehr interessante Grafiken. Aber was heißt »lütt« auf Standard-Deutsch?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast »klein«, wie englisch *little*

Comment: @Jan, Pommern oder Vorpommern? "lütt" kenne ich auch aus Mecklenburg. In Hamburg hätte ich es vom Bauchgefühl auch gesehen, aber dann ist mir eingefallen, dass es hier z.B. eher "klein Erna" statt "lütt Erna" heißt.

Comment: @Jan Naja, Vorpommern, aber sie hat das *Vor-* immer weggelassen. Wobei es von Greifswald aus ja wirklich nicht mehr weit bis Hinterpommern ist ;)

Comment: West-/Ostpommern paßt auch besser, als Vor-/Hinterpommern, wenn man da unbedingt eine Unterscheidung vornehmen will.

Comment: *Lütt* (engl. *wee* ;) gibt es auch in Berlin. Ich sage es nicht mehr, aber von meiner Mutter kenne ich es.

Answer (score 2):

Dich könnte das Plattdeutsche Wörterbuch interessieren:

- http://www.deutsch-plattdeutsch.de/wsuchen.php

In der Datenbank gibt es über 45000 Einträge. :D

Comment: Moin und danke für den Link! :-) Ich fürchte aber, ich finde dort keine Schibboleths...

Comment: @Jan. Doch, doch, ich hab auch direkt mal was schönes raus gesucht: Wörterbuch - Wordenbauk