# Is there a German sound that is similarly difficult for English speakers as th is for German speakers?

Tags: phonetics

Is  there a sound in the German language that is similarly difficult for English speakers as th is for German speakers?

Comment: "ü" and "ö" are very difficult to pronounce, at least for me.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/167/schibboleths-fur-verschiedene-norddeutsche-regionen

Comment: @Explorer “ö” is almost **exactly** the same sound that you get when pronouncing “further” with a British accent (i.e. with a silent “r”). The only difference is that in German the sound is usually closed. Not many people seem to know this.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Really? that's "ä" or "ö"? I pronounce "further" something like "ä". So I should improve my English before learning German!

Comment: @Explorer You had me momentarily surprised, but then I saw in your profile that you come from Norway. And indeed, my experience with Norwegians is that they would pronounce it more like “ä”. For the “ö” pronunciation, listen e.g. here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/further

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Gee, sorry for coming from Norway! and thank you.;)

Comment: @Explorer: hint for pronouncing "ü" - Say the i: sound and round your lips while doing so. Say "fiehl" with rounded lips and it will sound like "fühl". Similarly for "ö" - say the e: sound with rounded lips.

Comment: @Explorer “Gee, sorry for coming from Norway” – I’m in a good mood today, I forgive you. ;-)

Comment: @Explorer: for pronouncing the "ü", just say a Norwegian "u".

Comment: Is *th* in English **th**at hart? **Th**ere’s plenty of easy words, like ***th**ese* and ***th**ose*. Try competing with a German poem on *»Zwanzig Eichhörnchen auf’m Streichholzschächtelchen«*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the English language.

Comment: Funny enough: German people can't pronounce *squirrel*, and everyone else in the world can't pronounce *Eichhörnchen*.

Comment: Some people seem to have issues pronouncing the **sch** in Fleisch correctly (like fi**sh** in english). They prefer Flei**ch** instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [ulvular trill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill) of the German **r** is tricky for us. I can do it after a vowel but not very well at the start of a word.

The **ch** in *ich* takes a while to master, but mostly because beginners tend to assimilate it with English **sh**, not because it's terribly hard. The **ch** in *nach* is easier.

**ü** also takes a while to get to grips with.

I consider none of the other vowels (and diphthongs) difficult to articulate for an English speaker, but for a beginner it's natural to substitute them with a similar but different sound that's more familiar. In the same way, a English speaker with a non-rhotic accent may have a tendency to pronounce word-final -er as a schwa as in those varieties of English.

Comment: Indeed. I'll point out that with reading, all of the umlaut vowels cause problems. English doesn't have any diacritic marks, and so some people seem almost incapable of figuring out how to look for the umlaut when they're reading and just guess.

Comment: For the TeXnichians reading this: the ch in *nach* is spoken like the X in TeX.

Comment: @FUZxxl: That's because it's in the end of the word, right? Like "B" pronounced "P" in that position?

Comment: @FUZxxl wow, really? I didn't know TeX was supposed to be pronounced like that! I always thought it was pronounced "tek".

Comment: Like "g" in "fertig".

Comment: @fzwo: TeX stand for the greek letters tau-epsilon-chi and is thus pronounced [tɛχ] (although in Germany many peoply pronounce it [tɛç]).

Comment: ...Not to horrify anyone, but I have to say, I assumed it was pronounced the same way as latex. Non-computer person here...XD

Comment: @kitukwfyer: Exactly, I thought the same way. Latex. more non-computer person here!

Comment: @FUZxxl: No, TeX is _supposed_ (by Knuth) to be pronounced with a "ch" as in _nach_, but I don't know any German who does this. They all say it with a "ch" as in _ich_ or _frech_.

Comment: @Alenanno: No, the pronunciation of "ch" depends on the vowel _preceding_ it.

Comment: @Hendrik Isn't this exactly what I said?

Comment: @FUZxxl: Ah, I didn't see your 2nd comment. Still, my reply to your 1st comment would be "By whom??".

Answer (score 12):

Try to speak the German word for "matchbox"

> Streichholzschachtel [ˈʃtʀaɪ̯ç.hɔlʦˌʃaχ.tl̩]

and then you know, which consonants are difficult to pronounce.

Comment: OK, those clusters are hard. I might have to stick to "Das Ding, in dem die Dinge sind, mit denen man Feuer macht".

Comment: funny thing is, there isn't even a synonym for that in German. Not even in everyday language!

Comment: What about Zündholzschachtel, which is a bit easier?

Comment: Or "Zündholzbox"?

Comment: @ladybug: I suppose there are many words for which there is no synonym. Is there a synonym for *matchbox*?

Comment: @misterben: the sequence "lzsch" is the killer for me, so Zündholzschachtel is just as difficult.

Comment: In my region, we just say "Gib mir die Zünder."

Answer (score 5):

Most native English speakers have difficulties with the sound `ch`, pronounced like the guttural ch in Scottish "loch."

Also, the correct pronunciation of the different forms of `r` is a problem for many people from English speaking countries.

Answer (score 3):

My father (American) always had huge differences with the German R. He tended to form it from the tip of the tongue (rolling). I guess the difficult part was realizing how similar the German and English versions are.

Answer (score 3):

As a Brazilian, my native language is Brazilian Portuguese. I found it much, much easier to learn the German phonemes than the English ones, both to understand and to pronunce them.

However, there are some phonemes that are a bit tricky in German. The umlauted vowels are a bit of a challenge. However the `ch` is way harder. I can say I did not "get it" yet.

The `r` (uvular trill) is somewhat hard, too, but not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Try ,,tzsch''. I've seen in it only in names and even native speakers argue about how one should pronounce this. In upper saxon it is pronounced like ,,tsch'' (without the z).

Comment: Isn’t the “z” in “tzsch” *always* silent?

Comment: Tja, I guess that tells you how close to speaking Saxon we are here in Berlin :-)

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, I agree for single words, but I guess "Blitzschlag" is not easy.

Comment: @Phira: Given that the *tzsch* in that example spans a word boundary (within the compound), I don't think it's a good example. Otherwise, you could argue that English has the exact same thing, e.g. in a sentence like "Vince should leave." The *ce sh* would form the same combination of sounds, but there's no issue about that because the *ts* sound and the *sh* sound belong two different words and syllables.

Answer (score 1):

It's not simply a matter of the isolated sounds; their "phonetic context" also matters.  I have no problem with the sound at the end of *ich*, *dreißig*, *fertig*, etc. but I can't say *Eichhörnchen* at normal speed.

Comment: Try the Bavarian *Oachkatzlschwoaf* ;)